# rbind in lapply cannot understand date format

Tags: r, date, format, lapply, rbind

I have the following code:

```
    tradingDates <- c(as.Date("1996-12-31", format = "%Y-%m-%d" ), 
                      as.Date("1997-12-31", format = "%Y-%m-%d" ))
    d1 <- data.frame(CUSIP=c("039229109","M33228109"),
             Port.Weights=as.numeric(c("3.571429","4.976429")), 
             Trade.Date = as.Date("1996-12-31", format = "%Y-%m-%d" ), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    d2 <- data.frame(CUSIP=c("432764733","324K32586"),
             Port.Weights=as.numeric(c("6.243803","1.469823")), 
             Trade.Date = as.Date("1997-12-31", format = "%Y-%m-%d" ), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    myList <- list(d1, d2)

    thePorts <- lapply(seq_along(myList), function(x)
                       rbind(myList[[x]],
                             c("78462F10", 
                               sum(as.numeric((-.01)*myList[[x]]$Port.Weights[1])), 
                               as.Date(as.character(tradingDates[x]), format= "%Y-%m-%d")),
                             c("CASH_USD",
                               sum(as.numeric((.01)*myList[[x]]$Port.Weights[1])),
                               as.Date(as.character(tradingDates[x]), format= "%Y-%m-%d"))))
```

The error I am getting is:

```
     Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I have tried every method I can think of to format this date, and it should be noted that outside of the rbind and lapply, this line works fine:

```
    x=5
    format(as.Date(as.character(tradeDates[x]), format= "%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y%m%d")
```

Comment: The way you've shared your data makes it very hard to create a reproducible example (ie, I can't just copy and paste and run your code). But i think the problem is that you are converting to a date fine, but then you are formatting it (and converting to character) with ""%Y%m%d" which would be "19961213" and when it goes to rbind with other date values, you get that error because that's an invalid format. It would help if you clearly indicated your desired output for this code as well. There are many odd things like using `c()` for mixed data types, and incorrect `stringsAsFactors` params.

Comment: I have edited the code. You should be able to copy/paste and replicate the error I am getting. Thank you much for your time.

Comment: The edits made this much easier to answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your use of `c()` with mixed data. Types. `c()` is only for combining elements of the same type (unless overloaded by a package) so it will coerce everything to the same data.type. If you run

```
lapply(seq_along(myList), function(x)
    c("78462F10", 
    sum(as.numeric((-.01)*myList[[x]]$Port.Weights[1])), 
    as.Date(as.character(tradingDates[x]), format= "%Y-%m-%d")))

# [[1]]
# [1] "78462F10"    "-0.03571429" "9861"       
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "78462F10"    "-0.06243803" "10226"
```

You see that everything is converted to a string. This include the date which was first converted to numeric and here is represented by the number of days since Jan 1, 1970. While a simple vector can only hold data of one type, a `list()` is capable of holding data of different types. So change your code to

```
thePorts <- lapply(seq_along(myList), function(x)
    rbind(myList[[x]],
        list("78462F10", 
            sum(as.numeric((-.01)*myList[[x]]$Port.Weights[1])), 
            as.Date(as.character(tradingDates[x]), format= "%Y-%m-%d")),
        list("CASH_USD",
            sum(as.numeric((.01)*myList[[x]]$Port.Weights[1])),
            as.Date(as.character(tradingDates[x]), format= "%Y-%m-%d"))
    )
)
```

This returns

```
[[1]]
      CUSIP Port.Weights Trade.Date
1 039229109   3.57142900 1996-12-31
2 M33228109   4.97642900 1996-12-31
3  78462F10  -0.03571429 1996-12-31
4  CASH_USD   0.03571429 1996-12-31

[[2]]
      CUSIP Port.Weights Trade.Date
1 432764733   6.24380300 1997-12-31
2 324K32586   1.46982300 1997-12-31
3  78462F10  -0.06243803 1997-12-31
4  CASH_USD   0.06243803 1997-12-31
```

as desired (I assume)